# Create TemplateRef and insert it in component's template

Tags: angular

Angular 5.0.2
Based on the example provided on `NgTemplateOutlet` https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

I want to know if there's a way to dynamically create a TemplateRef and then inject it into component's template.

For example let's say a component has the following template

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="eng; context: myContext"></ng-container>
<ng-template #eng let-name><span>Hello {{name}}!</span></ng-template>
```

component code

```
class NgTemplateOutletExample {
  myContext = {$implicit: 'World'};
}
```

What I want is to transform this into a component with the following template

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="eng; context: myContext"></ng-container>
```

and component code like this

```
class NgTemplateOutletExample {
  eng:TemplateRef = this.createTemplateRef('<ng-template #eng let-name><span>Hello {{name}}!</span></ng-template>');
  myContext = {$implicit: 'World'};
}
```

Is it possible to create `TemplateRef` from a string?

Comment: I think it is possible, maybe not with ngTemplateOutlet though, look for 'Creating components on the fly' in https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

Comment: A TemplateRef is a reference to an existing template, you can only get one if the template exists, so there is no way of creating it dynamically. You can though create a component and instantiate that on dynamically without using it anywhere in the html templates directly.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is to have dynamic templates. So that you can put the template later without changing the same component.

Now how can you achieve this ?

*Create the main component renders the template. `<main-component>`*

## main.component.html

```
<div class="box">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="context"></ng-container>
</div>
```

## main.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @ContentChild("template")
  template :TemplateRef<any>;

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  get context(){
    return this;
  }

}
```

- Now you can the same component with different templates*

## app.component.html

```
<app-main>
  <ng-template #template>Content From First Template</ng-template>
</app-main>
<br>
<app-main>
  <ng-template #template>Content From Second Template</ng-template>
</app-main>
```

## Output

[image]

Working demo is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzkwrq

Comment: Note that passing "this" as context is awful, because `this` will contain a reference to the template itself, so it basically creates a loop.